Invariant Semi-Bounded Distributions under Hierarchical Transformation
I am interested in determining the set of semi-bounded distributions that remain invariant when they are part of a hierarchical model. For example, let
\begin{align}
 X\overset{iid}{\sim} p(x; \alpha)\\
 \alpha\overset{iid}{\sim} p(\alpha; \beta)\\
\end{align}
then
\begin{equation}
 X\overset{iid}{\sim} p(x; \beta)\\
\end{equation}
The formulation of this is:
\begin{equation}
   p(x, \beta) = \int_0^\infty p(x, \alpha) p(\alpha, \beta) d\alpha
\end{equation}
I have not found a general way of solving this, but I have found a specific solution: a variation of the log-normal distribution with median $m$ on the natural scale and standard deviation $\sigma$, specifically when the median has a hierarchical distribution.
\begin{equation}
   p(x; m, \sigma) = \frac{1}{x \sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{\ln^2\left(\frac{x}{m}\right)}{2\sigma^2}\right)
\end{equation}
So, this solution provides evidence that indeed such distributions do exist but it irks me that I cannot solve this problem more generally. If the community can assist me in understanding how to solve these types of functional problems, I would really appreciate it.
UPDATE 1:
Certain RV transformations also exhibit this behavior, namely those
\begin{align}
 Y &= \alpha X ^ \beta \\
 X &\sim LN(m,\sigma)
\end{align}
which provides the following pdf:
\begin{equation}
q(y; m, \sigma, \alpha, \beta) = \frac{1}{\sigma |\beta|y\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{\left(\ln \alpha + \beta \ln m - \ln y\right)^2}{2\beta^2\sigma^2}\right)
\end{equation}
which is still lognormal.
Finally, the mixture distribution of lognormal PDFs also meet the criteria, so
\begin{equation}
 r = \sum_{j=1}^J w_jq_j(y; m_j, \sigma_j, \alpha_j, \beta_j)
\end{equation}
where $0\le w_j \le 1$ and
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=1}^J w_j=1
\end{equation}
However, these are only expansions from the original insight that a special case of the lognormal distribution is invariant under hierarchical transformation. If it does not show that the lognormal is the only solution. That remains an open question for me.
UPDATE 2: (Under Construction)
If we assume the following relationship, we can begin to construct a subset of solutions:
\begin{equation}
 p(x;a) = q(x) r(a)
\end{equation}
This implies that a parameter $a$ can be factored out of the PDF. Note: this is not an ideal solution as it makes a pretty significant assumption about the structure of a solution, but it is arguably incremental progress.
From this, we obtain:
\begin{align}
 p(x; \beta) &= \int_0^\infty p(x;\alpha)p(\alpha; \beta) d\alpha\\
 &= \int_0^\infty q(x) r(\alpha) q(\alpha) r(\beta) d\alpha\\
 &= q(x) r(\beta) \int_0^\infty q(\alpha) r(\alpha) d\alpha\\
1 &= \int_0^\infty q(\alpha) r(\alpha) d\alpha\\
1 &= \int_0^\infty p(\alpha; \alpha) d\alpha\\
\end{align}
The way I interpret this is that the parameter within the PDF must be interchangeable with the independent variable of the PDF.
One example of this is when
\begin{align}
  q(x) &= 2 x e^{-x^2}\\
  r(\lambda) &= 2 \lambda e^{-\lambda^2}\\
  &\therefore\\
  p(x; \lambda) &= 4 x \lambda e^{-x^2-\lambda^2}
\end{align}
Update 3 (Under Construction):
If we build a hierarchical distribution of Pareto distributions where the location parameter is hierarchically distributed, we begin to see a similar pattern to the last hierarchical distribution. Generalizing this, we obtain:
\begin{equation}
  p(x; \alpha, \beta) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n!}\alpha^{1+n} \beta^\alpha x^{-1-\alpha} \ln^n \left(\frac{x}{\beta}\right) \text{I}_{(\beta, \infty)}(x)
\end{equation}

Could you please post links to references defining the terminology used (e.g. "semi-bounded" -- under what norm?, "invariant" -- under what transformation?). I agree that "hierarchical model" is fairly commonly used terminology at least. The premise of the question seems to be that "semi-bounded" distributions were already "invariant", but what either of those two terms means is probably unclear to most people. (I literally have a PhD in statistics and I don't know what you're referring to.) Also what you mean mathematically by "becoming part of a hierarchical model" is also unclear to me.

Thanks for commenting. Apologies at not being clear. I will attempt again. Semi-bounded is on the interval $[0, \infty)$, referring to semi-bounded support. I am trying to state that for some distribution with at least one parameter, this parameter too has a distribution (so a hierarchical distribution) and once you solve for the distribution of the hierarchical model, it has the same distribution form as the parameter. For example, if the RV X is distributed Stable distribution and the mean is also distributed Stable distribution, then the hierarchical model is distributed Stable.

So if you look at the example above, the lognormal distribution is on the interval $(0,\infty)$ and if we let $m$ be distributed log normally too, then if we solve the hierarchical model, we see that the resulting distribution remains lognormal. So the question is: is the lognormal distribution the only distribution over $(0,\infty)$ or $[0,\infty)$ with parameter $m$ that fulfills this relationship? Looks like some transformations as those described above still meet the requirement yet it is not clear if the lognormal and its transformations are special cases of a larger family.

Here's where I get confused -- at that point it almost seems like the semi-bounded condition is unnecessary / superfluous, right? Like by considering $e^X$ for $X$ semi-bounded, the support of the distribution is now all of $R$. So is the semi-bounded condition important in some other way? Or just an additional restriction being added to try to find uniqueness of the log normal distribution? To be honest, I don't think I know the answer to this question, but I just wanted to confirm you had heard about "exponential families of distributions", because your questions sounds very similar to that.

Compare box 17 here: https://www.randomservices.org/random/special/LogNormal.html So if you're talking about parameters that also have a distribution, even if there are frequentist interpretations of hierarchical models, Bayesians will also have studied this a lot (more). Have you ever read anything about Bayesian studies of exponential families? E.g. this https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/260-spring10/other-readings/chapter9.pdf How is what you're asking different from conjugate prior distributions that are semi-bounded? (It might be different, I'm just not clear either way)

What you are asking for sounds like a conjugate prior where not only the prior distribution (i.e. the distribution of the parameter) and the posterior distribution (i.e. the distribution of the hierarchical model) belong to the same family, but so do the likelihoods. Looking at this table of common conjugate priors from Wikipedia quickly, it seems like the Gamma distribution also satisfies the criteria you want (semi-bounded, and both the likelihood as well as the prior and posterior belong to same families) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior TL;DR have you tried the Gamma distrib.?

Thank you @Chill2Macht. I checked the Gamma distribution again after you mentioned it, and the posterior distribution when the model parameter $\beta$ is also Gamma distributed results in a Beta Prime distribution and not another Gamma distribution.

@Chill2Macht - Thanks for ensuring I have heard about the exp family of distributions. I took Mathematical Statistics and have been interested in finding those distributions that remain unchanged when their parameters take on a specific distribution and leave the overall distribution unchanged. The normal distribution (ND), the mean exists on $(-\infty, \infty)$ and if the mean is also ND, then you obtain the same type of distribution after you work it out. I want to know which distributions this works for a) $(-\infty, \infty)$, $[0,\infty)$, and $[a,b]$ where the last is a bounded interval.

Ultimately I don't know. I can just recommend that rephrasing the question in terms of conjugate priors, and maybe posting on stats.se, could lead to better answers.
